# Highlight foreground text using overpic?

Tags: highlighting, soul

I am using the `overpic` package to edit a pre-created pdf by writing notes in between the lines using `\put(){$$}` for each line.

Im having difficulty however using the `soul` package and `\hl` to highlight the existing writing of pdf as it highlights it in the foreground.

Is there a way to highlight the existing writing on the pdf in the background and maintain the original writing thus highlighting it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\vspace*{-28ex}
\hspace*{-30ex}
\begin{overpic}[width=9in,page=14]{file.pdf/jpg %%}
\put(20,29){}%using the number 10,20 puts writing over the highlight below%%i need the number to be the same so where would I incorporate my vspace and hspace and textwidth for the sHIPOUT%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
\put(30,115){\hl{\qquad\qquad\qquad% using \qquad to make a space for what is supposed       to be highlighted%}}}
\end{overpic}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\vspace*{-28ex}
\hspace*{-30ex}
\begin{overpic}[width=9in,page=15]{file.pdf/jpg %%}
\end{overspace}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

mY question is how do I get the Background to line up the same as any other \put within the overpic? Ive tried vspace and hspace separately on the shipout but doesnt seem to work, also how do i get it to go on just one page?

Comment: The `$` are not needed. You're reversing the order of the `\end` commands.

Comment: @egreg ok ill take the $ signs away

Answer (score 2):

As a general comment, you need to specify your code in the order that you want things to appear in the output PDF. That is, if you want something printed on the background, that should be first, followed by what goes on top of it, etc. The output for the PDF is produced in layers, hence the suggested order of usage. So, in your case, I would presume the following should do the trick:

1. Write your code containing the highlighting as well as the formulas; and then
2. Superimpose the external PDF page on top of your formatting.

[2] above should not influence [1], since there is blank spaces where you want to insert equations, and the highlight should be visible since it is larger than the overlaying text.

As an easy option (in my opinion), the [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) allows you to specify whether you want to print something in the background (`\AddToShipoutPictureBG*`), or in the foreground (`\AddToShipoutPictureFG*`). This way you could add the overlay/already-existing PDF using the latter, rather than the former. Or, since you tagged the question [pdfpages](/questions/tagged/pdfpages), I'm guessing that's what you're using to include the pages (via `\includepdf`).

If `eso-pic` is not your thing, then you'll have play around with positioning the `\includepdf` command so that the included PDF page fits overtop of your `\pic(<x>,<y>){$...$}` commands. This may be tricky.

As a final though, since you are placing the highlights on a line-by-line basis, you're probably not interested in line-breaking the highlights (which is something that `soul`'s `\hl{...}` does offer). So, you could also just use a coloured box as your "highlighting". Here's how to use coloured boxes (using [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
Here is some text \colorbox{yellow}{\phantom{here is some text}}.%
\end{document}​
```

You choose the highlighting colour (`yellow` in this case), and use `\phantom{...}` to remove the text but get the right spacing. Of course, in your example, you will place this text using `\pic`.

If your already-created PDF is an image (and therefore whitespace is not transparent), this will not work regardless of what you do, since you won't be able to get in "behind" the text and "in front" of the whitespace.

Comment: thanks, no im not wanting to include pdf pages. I dont think you understand the question. I basically trying to put a yellow bar in the background. I also dont want to use include pdf because Ive already got used to overpic. can i not just use eso-pic aswell then add \addtoshipoutFG*{\put(){\hl{}}}

Comment: OK i have managed to do it, i I able to answer a question then ask another one inside it,,

Comment: @john: You need to use `\AddToShipoutBG*{\put(<x>,<y>){...}}` to insert the highlighting in the background. Using `\...FG*` will put something in the foreground, overwriting the text behind it. Have you tried it with `\...BG*`?

Comment: yeah, actually it worked with \AddToPicture{} and the eso-pic package nicely, no idea why. Its just , because I also embedded a \put(){} for that line it doesnt quite line up as it would if I hadnt put add to picture if you see what I mean,,i have to play with those number which is a bit inpractical. anyway around this? '',

Comment: actualy it turns out that i havent solved it at all, as it highlights everypage :( see original question

Comment: when i use AddToShipoutPictureBG{\put(<>,<>){\hl{\qquad }}} it works on everypage,,that is exclusing your * symbol @werner and including the Picture as well..any ideas how to get it on one page.

Comment: when i put * which should allow it to be on one page the highlight disapears :(

Comment: @john: Oh, I see. I'll have to look into this. I know that `\hl` from `soul` (or just `soul` in general) has some intricate coding that may break depending on the environments its used inside.

Comment: thanks. yeah , maybe I would be better using another type of highlighting function rather than opting for this default one with package 'soul'. But for now I cant underestimate the power of using overpic and switch to pdfpages or tikz within each page. I like it even though iM getting blue warning everywhere saying the picture is out of line :P..so yeah, if you can think of a way, for now ill use adobe to highlight the final thing which is a little inconvenient

Comment: @john: I've added an alternative using `\colorbox`. Haven't tried it with `\pic`, but it should be more robust than `\hl`.

Comment: hmm ive tried it with put if thats what you mean and it just went n front of the pdf writing that was on the pdf i inserted with overpic. i dont know really how the \pic works but ill look into it. is it \put{} :S

Comment: good news, it worked \AddToShipoutFG*{\put(<%><%>){\qquad\qquad}} only problem is I only know as far as to use \AtPageCentre{} and it only does it on the first page(which is good no doubt) but Im going to  have great difficulty i imagine getting it on the correct line on one of 20 pages when the number <%><%> in the \put(<%><%>) are totally ignored? anyone know how i could fine tune that. iT SEEMS WHEREVER i put the overpic defining a page the addtoshipout completely ignores which page and goes to page 1 if you see what I mean, i.e page 1 of the latex document.

Comment: @john: Do you mean `\hl` or `\colorbox`? And do you mean `\...BG*` or `\...FG*`?

Comment: @ werner below, no your original 'BG*' worked with '\hl' and im afraid xcolor along with \put didnt . I dont know how to use \pic , cheers,,,getting there though see above comment^{{ and it worked in that it goes behind the overpic's text}} i guess it will be a daunting task of studying the eso-pic manual to get it spot on a lin e each time,,unless someone is really familiar

Comment: anyone know how to put thr highlight on a specific page at a sepcific place then?